# What is going on with this "POST for loop" in python? -- Python noob

Tags: python, pyscripter

I understand the code below except for the sum function call below. I dont understand the logic of what exactly does a sum function accept as its argument? Whats the for loop in there? what is that thing??

```
def sim_distance(prefs,person1,person2):
  # Get the list of shared_items
  si={}
  for item in prefs[person1]:
    if item in prefs[person2]: si[item]=1

  # if they have no ratings in common, return 0
  if len(si)==0: return 0

  # Add up the squares of all the differences
  sum_of_squares=sum([pow(prefs[person1][item]-prefs[person2][item],2)
                      for item in si])

  return 1/(1+sum_of_squares)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So there are two concepts at work there - `sum` and a list comprehension.

```
sum_of_squares=sum([pow(prefs[person1][item]-prefs[person2][item],2)
                      for item in si])
```

First, the list comprehension.

```
[pow(prefs[person1][item]-prefs[person2][item],2) for item in si]
```

This can be broken down into a `for` loop that would look like this:

```
result_list = [] # Note that this is implicitly created
for item in si:
    result_list.append(pow(prefs[person1][item]-prefs[person2][item], 2))
```

That creates a list of values by running the `pow` function on each iteration, using each `item` in `si` and appending the result to `result_list`. Let's say that loop results in something like `[1, 2, 3, 4]` - now all that `sum` is doing is summing each element of the list and returning the result.

As to your question of what the `sum` function accepts as an argument, it is looking for an iterable, which is anything that can be iterated over (a string, a list, keys/values of dictionaries, etc.). Just like you see with `for` loops, `sum` adds each item in the iterable (list in this case) and returns the total. There is also an optional `start` argument, but I would focus on understanding the base functionality first :)

Answer (score 1):

This is just a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) -so your 'for' loop is used to build a list of diff values in power of two

it is pretty the same like:

```
lVals = []
for item in si:
    lVals.append(pow(prefs[person1][item]-prefs[person2][item],2))

sum_of_squares = sum(lVals)
```